# Php Localhost Error

Tags: php, html, css

This html file is working fine when I have opened it from normal folder,but it was not working when i've tried to open it from localhost. CSS and Image items are not loading. Only tags and divs are showing. I think  the problem is with `href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. How can i solve this issue?

```
    <!-- Optional theme -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/main.css">

    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/owl.theme.css">

<!-- Include Jquery -->
    <script src="public/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="public/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the folder structure?

Comment: if is it a file then what it's name? you need to put it in your xampp/wamp/lamp htdocs folder  and call on browser like localhost/filename. So try like this and tell what is happening. And if folder then structure is required

Comment: If your `public` folder is on root then place `href="<?php echo baseurl();?>...`

Comment: /var/www/html/Bagıs  . this is my folder where the website in.

Comment: http://localhost/Bagıs/index.html this works but picture and other css file does not seem

Comment: @el_Pueblo_13 /var/www/html/Bagıs/public/ is the correct path of public folder ?

Comment: if i start with like tihs "file:///var/www/html/bagissitesi/bagisyap.html" it runs . but if i start with "localhost/bagissitesi/bagisyap.html" it occurs an error . "You don't have permission to access /bagissitesi/ on this server."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were three problems:

1. Make sure that your folder should be reside under htdocs folder for xampp or lampp or under www folder for wamp.
2. If your index file is under public folder, then folder structure should be proper.
3. Lastly, when everything is perfect then press Cntl+F5, this will reload your css and js file.

Comment: if i start with like tihs "file:///var/www/html/bagissitesi/bagisyap.html" it runs . but if i start with "localhost/bagissitesi/bagisyap.html" it occurs an error . "You don't have permission to access /bagissitesi/ on this server."

Comment: Allow your project folder to add 777 permission using chmod command ie. **chmod -R 777 bagissitesi** and press enter

Answer (score 1):

Try following CSS include statement:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```